# @ is for matmul/inner, what's for the outer product?

Tags: python, numpy

In Python, the `@` operator relays to the `__matmul__` property of an element. This comes in handy when implementing a method that stays agnostic of the actual backend. For example

```py
def inner(x, y):
    return x @ y
    # same:
    # return x.__matmul__(y)
```

implements an inner product, for `x`, `y` being numpy arrays or any other fancy array class.

Is there a similar such API for the *outer* product, too?

Comment: [No](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions)

Comment: With a suitable mix of dimensions and `broadcasting`, the `*` element-wise multiplication performs the outer product.  `@` can do that as well, if the sum-of-products dimension is size 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@` operator was added as [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) for `__matmul__`. There is no such thing (and no dunder method) for the outer product.

In fact, the outer product is a simple multiplication (`*`) once the first array got reshaped:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([10, 100])

np.outer(a, b)

a[:,None] * b
```

Output of both products:

```
array([[ 10, 100],
       [ 20, 200],
       [ 30, 300]])
```

Comment: `a[:,None]@b[None,:]` also does that `outer`.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, my point is that there is no special operator it could be done with existing operators